# Making the calls directly from java to javascript with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm writing a native plugin to raise an event in JavaScript when the keyboard is showing. I do this:

```
appView.sendJavascript("cordova.fireWindowEvent('show_keyboard')")
```

In my JavaScript I then do something like:

```
window.addEventListener('show_keyboard', handler);
```

However, this has been flagged as a big no no in PhoneGap by a PhoneGap expert on the team. What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Could you please explain further the end goal? I am not 100% clear on `to raise an event in javascript when the keyboard is showing`. Are you wanting the plugin to know when the keyboard is showing? And if so, what should the plugin do, if it is?

Comment: What did the "PhoneGap expert" give as their reasoning?

Comment: I think the reason this approach isn't acceptable is one of organisation - javascript mixed in with java. In the end, I passed a javascript callback to the java and this was acceptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

Well I too am no PhoneGap expert, but [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), [the engine that powers PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/) has [its source on GitHub](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android).

#### What does the source say?

Well, as an example, let's look at how Cordova sends its [`volumedownbutton` event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#volumedownbutton). I present [lines 613–621 of CordovaWebView.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/cc860804f6d55ba0758b2b89e8f3f5d60fee0923/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L613-L621):

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
    this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumedownbutton');");
    return true;
}
// If volumeup key
else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
    this.loadUrl("javascript:cordova.fireDocumentEvent('volumeupbutton');");
    return true;
}
```

It would seem that Cordova employs a similar approach to sending events to JavaScript.

#### What's wrong with what you have?

I am not sure what the exact issue was that your coworker raised, but it does seem that [`sendJavascript` is deprecated](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/cc860804f6d55ba0758b2b89e8f3f5d60fee0923/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L476-L499). So, there's that. But if your `appView` is a `CordovaWebView`, the you can just call [`loadUrl`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/cc860804f6d55ba0758b2b89e8f3f5d60fee0923/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java#L331) in the same way the that Cordova itself does it (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

I am no phonegap expert, but why don't you just call the method directly instead of using listeners?

for example

```
function keyboardShown() {
    alert("test"); //or other code
}
```

and

```
appView.sendJavascript("keyboardShown();")
```

This way you remove the overhead which you have through the listener.

If this still doesn't satisfy your phonegap expert, ask him what he would do to improve this code.